# Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type at malloc?

Tags: c

I watched the other two questions about this problem, but I think they are different. Thanks for your help. Problem is in the 18th line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct x {
   char name1[30];
   char name2[30];
} x;

int main() {
    int *ptr;
    x array[2] = {
        { "Apple", "Battle" },
        { "Cup", "Dog" },
    };
    ptr = (x*)malloc(sizeof(x)); /*assignment from incompatible pointer type*/
    printf("write something");
    scanf("%s", array[3].name1);

    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem in some words. Are you getting a warning, an error or unexpected output? If there are other questions about this problem, clearly link to them and say why the respective solutions do not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems in your code:

- You cast the return value of `malloc()` as `(x*)` but store it to a pointer to `int` instead of a pointer to `x`.  Why do you do this?  If properly configured for useful warnings, the compiler will diagnose a potential error here.
- `scanf("%s", array[3].name1);` stores a word into the `name1` member of a member of `array` that has not been defined. The size of the `array` is `2`, the only valid index values as `0` and `1`. This code invokes undefined behavior.
- The `%s` `scanf` format would also cause a potential buffer overflow since `scanf` can try an store more that 29 characters plus a null terminator into the member.  You should use `%29s`.
- What is the purpose of your function?